# rand() function in c++ generate even and odd number with a periodic of 3276800 ,who know why?

Tags: c++, random

```
for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
{
    for(int i=0;i<3276800;i++)
    {
        cout<<(rand()%2)<<'\n';
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

The first 3276800 and the second 3276800 are the same.
The number of rand() is not the same, but the odevity is the same;
why?

Comment: Only two loops? This would be a significant observation if you saw it in more loops as well. Since `rand` is (presumably) *random*, you could well get your value two, ten, or one hundred times in a row. (But `rand` is not random.)

Comment: @user2737230: Please clarify: do you want to know *why* `rand` behaves this way, or do you need "more random random numbers"?

Comment: Obligatory Dilbert reference http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2001-10-25/

Comment: odevity? A new one on me.

Comment: http://www.c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html

Comment: @Jongware: 2 loops is sufficient if you are testing 3276800 (3.2 million) values. The odds of an actual random number generator producing a sequence of 6553600 numbers where the first half is equal to the second half are **very, very** low.

Comment: Why do you care?  If you have proven the low bit is not random and you want random, then do not use the low bits.

Comment: I really don't get that this is flagged as a duplicate of a question where a random generator is wrongly seeded before each call. Above question is about a periodic repeat of the low bit of a random generator. The only thing in common of the two questions is that they involve a random generator.

Answer (score 14):

The RNG used by most implementations of `rand` is a [*linear congruential generator*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator). These tend to have very poor periods in the low-order bits; very naive implementations may have a period of just 2 in the low order bit (i.e. alternating 0 and 1).

Better implementations return only the high 16 bits of the random value, discarding the poor-quality low-order bits. In such an implementation, the low-order bit will have period at most 2^16 = 65536. Since 65536 divides 3276800 evenly, you will see a periodic pattern.