# C: Random walk (Brownian motion) program does not return expected theoretical value. Why?

Tags: c, random, probability

This is just an experiment based on section 6-3 in "Feynman Lectures on Physics":

> In its simplest version, we imagine a “game” in which a “player”
>   starts at the point x=0 and at each “move” is required to take a step
>   either forward (toward +x) or backward (toward −x). The choice is to
>   be made randomly, determined, for example, by the toss of a coin.

Source: http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_06.html#Ch6-S3

My objective is to calculate the expected distance from the stating point.  So, I suppose that each step is equal to one unit of distance.  I wrote a simple C program to simulate 30 random steps, then calculate the final distance from the starting point.  This is repeated for a million times, and the program averages the distance to get the expected distance.

Theoretically, the expected distance should be the square root of the number of the steps.  That should be about sqrt(30) = 5.48.

However, the program is run few times and keeps returning a value near to 4.33 (to be more exact, 4.33461, 4.33453, and 4.34045).  Why is it not even near to the theoretical value of about 5.48?

Here is my code:

```
#include    <time.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <stdio.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{

  int number_of_steps = 30;
  int repetition = 1000000;
  int distance = 0;
  int total_distance = 0;
  double expected_distance;
  int i, j;

  srand(time(NULL));

  for ( i = 0; i < repetition; i++ ) {

    for ( j = 0; j < number_of_steps; j++) {
      distance += rand() & 1 ? -1 : 1;
    }

    total_distance += abs(distance);
    distance = 0;

  }

  expected_distance = (float) total_distance / i;

  printf ( "%g\n", expected_distance );
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}       /* ----------  end of function main  ---------- */
```

Comment: From the lecture you linked to, it looks like your theoretical expectation is based on the [root mean square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square), whereas your code is a simple [arithmetic mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean).

Comment: Theoretically, that is, if `rand()` returns equal amounts of `0` and `1`, you should always end up with a distance of 0. I noticed increasing the amount of steps by a factor 10 increases your expected distance with sqrt(10) -- that may or may not mean anything.

Comment: @Jongware check out the lecture notes, it's a bit less direct than that.

Comment: @Jongware: The distance of `0` is the *most probable* outcome of a *single experiment*. That does not mean that you should always get it. In real experiments you will get different distances. If you average *signed* distances then you should indeed get around `0`. But once we start talking about the *absolute* distances and average them, `0` is no longer the winner.

Comment: Indeed, if you use the root mean square average, [the code](http://ideone.com/esfzAI) gives you the expected vale.

Comment: @wolfPack88: sounds like the answer, not a comment :)

Comment: Wow, I feel so dumb.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @vxs8122: No worries, we all have our moments. I've added it as an answer now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the lecture you linked to, your theoretical expectation is based on the [root mean square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square), which is different from the [arithmetic mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean), which is what you have coded. By changing the algorithm from one to the other, [the code](http://ideone.com/esfzAI) now gives you the expected results.

```
for ( i = 0; i < repetition; i++ ) {

    for ( j = 0; j < number_of_steps; j++) {
      distance += rand() & 1 ? -1 : 1;
    }

    total_distance += distance * distance;
    distance = 0;

  }

  expected_distance = sqrt((float) total_distance / repetition);

  printf ( "%g\n", expected_distance );
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Small question: why use a `float` cast for arguments for `sqrt()` vs. `double` with `sqrt()` or `float` with `sqrtf()`?  Never mind - I see that is what OP did.

Answer (score 2):

[The answer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558318/rand-function-in-c-generate-even-and-odd-number-with-a-periodic-of-3276800) suggests that using the low-order bit(s) of rand() is unlikely to be a great choice.

I'd try a different way of generating your +1 or -1.